# Array element search

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to java and have been trying to write how to search multidimensional arrays. My code works for elements found but when I enter an element that does not match, it does not printout anything. Please tell me what's wrong with my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ArraySearch {
public static void main (String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //lets create the array
    int [] [] arrayOfInts = {{1, 2,3,4}, {5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12}};

    //create search variables
    System.out.println("Enter the key number to search for in the array: ");
    int key = input.nextInt();
    boolean foundIt;

    //perform search using a for loop
    for (int i = 0; i <arrayOfInts.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j <arrayOfInts[i].length; j++){
            if (arrayOfInts[i][j] == key) {
                foundIt = true;

                if (foundIt) {
                    System.out.println("found " + key + " at row " +i+ " column " +j);

                } else {
                    System.out.println(key + "is not in the array");  
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: @АлександрГончаренко a `boolean` can't be `null`. It's uninitialised, but not `null`.

Comment: Also ..you can break from the loop when you found the element , no need to iterate over all

Comment: Please try to use a correct code style (format). I like the [Google Java Style](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html), but you can also find other styles on Google. By using a proper style, you can easily detect quite a lot of mistakes in the code. It also increases the general readability.

Comment: The default value for bool is not null . Src: execute command Java InitialValues ..for bool it is false not null

Comment: @Paul it would only print something if `arrayOfInts[i][j] == key` evaluated to `true`, because all the print statements are inside that `if` block.

Comment: @Paul It wouldn't print on every test, as the print is inside the test, so it would only print on a successful test (which is what OP stated).

Answer (score 3):

You should initialize your boolean to false, since local variables must be initialized before being used :

```
boolean foundIt = false;
```

Otherwise, if the key wasn't found, `foundIt` would be uninitialized when you access it in your if condition.

Not initializing `foundIt` should have given you a compliation error (`The local variable foundIt may not have been initialized`), but you have another error that hid this error. Your if statement that prints the output should be outside the for loops. Now it's inside the condition that finds a match, so it would only be evaluated if you found a match.

Comment: The default value of a `boolean` in Java is `false`.

Comment: @brimborium It still needs to be initialised for the code to compile.

Comment: @brimborium That's true only for class members. Local variables must be initialized.

Comment: @Paul It's part of the problem (you can't solve the problem without fixing this). I edited my answer to make it complete.

Answer (score 1):

Your bracketing is wrong. The if - else statement

```
if (foundIt) {
    System.out.println("found " + key + " at row " +i+ " column " +j);

} else 
        {System.out.println(key + "is not in the array");  
}
```

Is inside the check of the for loop.

```
if (arrayOfInts[i][j] == key) {
```

You probably want to have it inside of the for loop to show the message for each match. But then you should just put a println message inside the if statement in the for loop

```
if (arrayOfInts[i][j] == key) {
  System.out.println("found " + key + " at row " +i+ " column " +j);
```

And to print the other message when the key was never found, but this has to be done at the end. Make sure you initialize the boolean in the beginning!

```
boolean foundIt = false;
...
//at the end
if(!foundIt) {
  System.out.println("found " + key + " at row " +i+ " column " +j);
}
```

Comment: @Paul No it only prints inside the if of the for. So only when a match is found in the if statement, where the foundIt is set to true.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your code to following. There are many issues in your code. You have to make correct order of `{}`, If you do so you needs to initialize `foundIt`

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    //lets create the array
    int[][] arrayOfInts = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}};
    //create search variables
    System.out.println("Enter the key number to search for in the array: ");
    int key = input.nextInt();
    boolean foundIt = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfInts.length; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < arrayOfInts[i].length; j++) {
          if (arrayOfInts[i][j] == key) {
            System.out.println("found " + key + " at row " + i + " column " + j);
            // if found it will change the foundIt to true
            foundIt = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!foundIt) {
        System.out.println(key + "is not in the array");
    }
```

Comment: Why cant we break when the element is found in the array ?

Comment: @SaiAvinash yes we can break. But what happen if there are duplicate elements? and needs to find them too?

Comment: I wouldn't break, it displays row and column and that makes every output unique. If you would just want to know if it was found then you could break to be faster. But this implementation is more complete as it shows all matches.

Answer (score 0):

```
// perform search using a for loop
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfInts.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arrayOfInts[i].length; j++) {
            if (arrayOfInts[i][j] == key) {
                    System.out.println("found " + key + " at row " + i + " column "
                            + j);
                    return;         
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(key + "is not in the array");
```

I just added a return on finding the desired element and cut/paste the else branch to the end of the loop.

Comment: the inner if-clause is not necessary because you set foundIt to true

Answer (score 0):

Your System.out is only inside this if-block

```
if (arrayOfInts[i][j] == key)
```

so if you don't find something the is no printout

I would do it in this way:

```
...
for (int i = 0; i <arrayOfInts.length; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j <arrayOfInts[i].length; j++){
        if (arrayOfInts[i][j] == key) {
            foundIt = true;
            // Tell where you found it
            System.out.println("found " + key + " at row " +i+ " column " +j);
        }
    }
}
// After all check whether you found something anytime
if(!foundIt){
    System.out.println(key + "is not in the array");  
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your print statements the if (foundIt) ... else block is within the if (arrayOfInts[i][j] == key) block. This means that if the int is not found, the code never enters that inner if check where you print.
You can move the "not found" to the end.
For example:

```
    boolean foundIt = false;
    // perform search using a for loop
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfInts.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < arrayOfInts[i].length; j++)
        {
            if (arrayOfInts[i][j] == key)
            {
                foundIt = true;
                System.out.println("found " + key + " at row " + i + " column " + j);
            }

        }
    }
    if (!foundIt)
    {
        System.out.println(key + "is not in the array");
    }
```

Don't forget to initialize the foundIt to false first.

Answer (score 0):

**My Suggested Solution is :**

```
bool foundit=false;

for (int i = 0; i <arrayOfInts.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j <arrayOfInts[i].length; j++){
            if (arrayOfInts[i][j] == key)
            {
            foundIt = true;
            break;
            System.out.println("found " + key + " at row " +i+ " column " +j);
           }
      }
}

if(!foundit)
{
system.out.println("Key not found in the array.")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ArraySearch {
public static void main (String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //lets create the array
    int [] [] arrayOfInts = {{1, 2,3,4}, {5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12}};

    //create search variables
    System.out.println("Enter the key number to search for in the array: ");
    int key = input.nextInt();

    //perform search using a for loop
    for (int i = 0; i <arrayOfInts.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j <arrayOfInts[i].length; j++){
            if (arrayOfInts[i][j] == key) {
                System.out.println("found " + key + " at row " +i+ " column " +j);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(key + " is not in the array");
}
}
```

Why:
commands in operator`if (arrayOfInts[i][j] == key) {}` executing only if the element is found in array, so it is no need to use your `boolean foundIt;`. Use `return` to end executing the class, cos we have found what we wanted. The line `System.out.println(key + " is not in the array");` should be after the two cycles so it will work only if we've checked each element of the two-dimensional array before.